# spark dataset value calculation based on other dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with three values, "Date","accountid" and "item", I need to make some calculation when the account id is missing for a given day in a 10 day range period, the approach I took was to create a dataframe with empty dates for last 10 days and compare it against original dataset to see if the account id is missing. In my final output I need to make calculation for each account id, iresepctive of they show up for that day on the original  dataset. Here is what I tried.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2018-06-01","id1","small"),
  ("2018-06-01","id1","small"),  
    ("2018-06-01","id1","small"),                                                        
  ("2018-06-02","id1","small"),
  ("2018-06-03", "id2","medium"),
    ("2018-06-03", "id2","medium"),
    ("2018-06-08", null,null),         
  ("2018-06-04", "id1","small"),
  ("2018-06-06", "id3","large"))).toDF("date","accountid","item")
df.show

+----------+---------+------+
|      date|accountid|  item|
+----------+---------+------+
|2018-06-01|      id1| small|
|2018-06-01|      id1| small|
|2018-06-01|      id1| small|
|2018-06-02|      id1| small|
|2018-06-03|      id2|medium|
|2018-06-03|      id2|medium|
|2018-06-08|     null|  null|
|2018-06-04|      id1| small|
|2018-06-06|      id3| large|
+----------+---------+------+
```

I am thinking of broadcasting unique accounid's and item values

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val idList = df.select(collect_set("accountid")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0)
val itemList=df.select(collect_set("item")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0)
```

and compare the original dataset against the date dataset.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val dateTime = LocalDate.now()
var startDate=dateTime.minusDays(10)
val stop = dateTime
var dateArray = new ListBuffer[LocalDate]()
while (startDate.isBefore(stop)) {
            dateArray+=startDate
            startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
}
val dateList=dateArray.toList.map(_.toString)
dateList.toDF.show

+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|2018-07-04|
|2018-07-05|
|2018-07-06|
|2018-07-07|
|2018-07-08|
|2018-07-09|
|2018-07-10|
|2018-07-11|
|2018-07-12|
|2018-07-13|
+----------+
```

And final output I am expecting something like this.

```
+----------+---------
|     value|dayaggregate
+----------+---------
|2018-07-04|[[id1-> [small=0,medium=1..],[id2->[small=1,medium=0,..]]]
|2018-07-05|[[id1-> [small=0,medium=1..],[id2->[small=1,medium=0,..]]]
```

what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: you can make use of the Windowing functions. Also, your final output is not fully visible, if you can post full final output.

Comment: I need make calculations for each day for each user for the last x days, I am not sure window function will help